# Get a cell location from a given value and find the value on the right from cell location from Excel using EPPlus and Linq

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

This is what I want to have

Find the location of the value "arriere" in an Excel sheet and get the value next to it.

```
column I row 35 = "arriere"
column J row 35 = 1456.00
```

Right now I'm using the following code :

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(f.FullName))

 {
       var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
       var montantArriere = from cell in worksheet.Cells["G:L"]
           where cell.Value?.ToString() == "Total Arriéré" 
           select worksheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row, 10].Value;
}
```

The code works but if the value "arriere" change of column I won't be able to find the value next to it since the `cell.Start.Row` is set by 10 from the start.

Is there any way to have the value next to "arriere" more dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Offset on cell to get a cell based on the offset you choose. (row, column)

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(f.FullName))

 {
       var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
       var montantArriere = from cell in worksheet.Cells["G:L"]
           where cell.Value?.ToString() == "Total Arriéré" 
           select cell.Offset(0,1).Value;
}
```